# startService after startActivity freezes my android application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-pendingintent

I have the below code which freezes after the application has navigated from one activity to another. I checked my logcat for any errors but there is none. Could you please help me out with the solution? Thanks.

My service class

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service
{
private Timer timer1 = new Timer();
private Timer timer2 = new Timer();

private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 25000;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    _startService();

}

private void _startService() {
    timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Timer started1");
            Leavenotification(MyAlarmService.this);
            Timesheetnotification(MyAlarmService.this); 
        }
    }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

this is how I am starting the service and activity

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    intent.putExtra("userID", userID);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    startService(new Intent(this,MyAlarmService.class);
```

I am not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Debugging a service requires more than LogCat, I would suggest to go through [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

A service doesn't automatically run in another thread and your service doesn't make any effort to start a workerthread.

Also `onStart(...)` is deprecated and your service is a "bound" and "started" service which is generally fine, but if not really needed, i'd decide to use only one. The easiest way is probably using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which handles threading for you, but has some limitations.

I'd advise to have a look at the [official service tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and get familiar with the difference between a "bound" and "started" service.

Bottom line, check out [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) first and see if it fits your need, if not you will have to handle threading in your service yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start the another activity your current activity goes to background. And your current activity will not not be running on the main thread..But the service needs to running on the main thread.. A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process. try doing this

```
startService(new Intent(this,MyAlarmService.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare your Service in your manifest.

```
<service class=".MyService" name=".MyService">
       <intent-filter>
           <action
            android:value="sample.service.MY_SERVICE"
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:process="another_thread"/>
    </intent-filter>
       </service>
```

And use this propierty.
android:process="another_thread"

Use this like reference.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#exported